# Wordpress loop skips to else statement after contact form submit

Tags: php, html, wordpress, loops, contact-form

I am creating a fairly basic website on wordpress with a few sections including news and contact etc. The content is all on one page.

On first load the page works just fine and displays everything correctly. However, once I submit a message through my contact form the page reloads and the loop does not show any posts, it just displays 'no posts found' from the else statement in the Wordpress loop.

I wondered if anyone had encountered anything similar? I shall paste in the code sections once I am home from work, but any solutions or possibilities are welcome for the time being.

Code for looping posts and displaying on main page. This is in an external file that I use php to include in the index.php page.

```
  <?php 

        if (have_posts()) :
            query_posts('posts_per_page=3');
            while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
            <div class="postContainerHome">
                <div class="postImageHome">
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('small-thumbnail'); ?></a>

                </div>

                <div class="postTitleHome">
                    <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>

                </div>

                <div class="postContentHome">
                    <?php echo wp_trim_words(get_the_content(), 20, '...' ); ?>

                </div>

                <div class="readMoreButton">
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><p class="noSelect">Read More</p></a>
                </div>

            </div>


            <?php endwhile; 

            else :
                echo '<p>Oops, there are no posts! Please try refreshing the page.</p>';

            endif;

?>
```

Contact form, also an external file that I include in both the index.php page at the bottom and on a single contact page.

```
    <section class="contact">
    <div class="sectionSubHead">
        <p class="noSelect">- Get in touch -</p>
    </div>

    <div class="sectionHead">
        <h1 class="noSelect">Contact Us</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="contactFormPrompt">
        <?php
            $name = $_POST['name'];
            $email = $_POST['email'];
            $message = $_POST['message'];
            $from = 'From: Contact Form'; 
            $to = 'email@address.com'; 
            $subject = 'Message from Contact Form';
            $human = $_POST['human'];

            $body = "From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Message:\n $message";

                if ($_POST['submit'] && $human == '4' && $name != '' && $email != '' && $email != '') {              
                    if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) { 
                        echo '<p>Your message has been sent!</p>';

                    } else { 
                    echo '<p>Something went wrong, go back and try again!</p>';             

                    } 

                } else if ($_POST['submit'] && $human != '4') {
                    echo '<p>You need to fill in all required fields!</p>';

                }
        ?>
    </div>


    <div class="contactFormContainer">
        <form action="" method="post">
            <input name="name" placeholder="Full Name*">

            <input name="email" type="email" placeholder="Email*">

            <textarea name="message" placeholder="Message*"></textarea>

            <input name="human" placeholder="What is 2+2?* (Verification)">

            <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Send">

        </form>

    </div>

</section>
```

This is just a simple contact form I made following a tutorial, so it may not be the best, but I am not sure what is causing the problem.

Comment: In order for us to help you, we'll definitely need to see the code. It will also be helpful to see the URI pattern before/after form submission.

Comment: I tried removing my contact form and adding a very basic one instead, but got the same result in the end. So I am assuming the problem lies somewhere in the post loop.

Comment: Again, what does the URI change to on form submit? Are there `$_GET` variables?

Comment: I am running on local right now, so the home page is just localhost/WP. When I use the contact form on the homepage it simply returns the same URI. However if I use the contact form on the contact page localhost/WP/contact-us it returns the same localhost/WP/contact-us, but displays the homepage instead. There are no $_GET variables.